# Independence and correlation of the sum of normal random variables

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution

Suppose we have two independent normal random variables $X$ and $Y$ with mean $1$ and variance $2$. 
Now consider we have following:

- $X + Y$
- $X - Y$

The question is if $X + Y$ and $X - Y$ are correlated/uncorrelated and independent/not independent (or none of the statements is correct).

***Edit:*** Found suitable formula to check the correlation beetwen given random variables.
$$cov(X+Y)=E((X+Y)(X-Y))+E(X+Y)E(X-Y)$$

$$E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)=2$$
$$E(X-Y)=E(X)-E(Y)=0$$

$$cov(X+Y)=E((X+Y)(X-Y))+2\cdot0=E(X^2-Y^2)$$
$$cov(X+Y)=E(X)E(X)-E(Y)E(Y)=1-1=0$$

If there are no mistakes made, it proves the fact that $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are not correlated. However, still no thoughts on independence case.

Comment: Your thoughts? What did you try?

Comment: @StubbornAtom updated, but still don't know what to do with the independence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Being independent, $\ X, Y\ $ are [bivariate normally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case) distributed, and hence so are $\ X+Y, X-Y\ $.  You can tell whether $\ X+Y\ $ and $\ X-Y\ $ are independent or not by looking at their joint density function, which depends only on their means, variances and correlation coefficient.

Comment: So, I should check if $f_{X+Y,X−Y}$ and $f_{X+Y} \cdot f_{X−Y}$ are equal. Getting $f_{X+Y}$ and $f_{X−Y}$ is pretty obvious, but I didn't know how to get $f_{X+Y,X−Y}$. For it I need to use the formula you linked for, right?

Comment: Yes, once you have the means and variances of $\ X+Y\ $ and $\ X-Y\ $, and their covariance, that seems to me to be the simplest approach.